# sigma algebra of a sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

For some set $D \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, is it true in general that $\sigma(\sigma(D)) = \sigma(D)$? The backwards inclusion is obvious but I am not sure if the forwards inclusion is true.

Comment: Recall the definition of $\sigma(M)$. It's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually simple; for,
if $\mathscr{F}$ is a sigma-algebra, then 
$$
\sigma (\mathscr{F}) = \mathscr{F}.
$$

Comment: And this even an equivalence.